# Is there a way watch multiple issues and reviews in a single place?

Tags: github, jira, gerrit

I am wondering if anyone builded a tool that can watch things like:

- github bugs (multiple projects)
- gerrit reviews (multiple gerrit instances, I already have patches in 3)
- jira bugs (multiple instances)

Clearly such a tool would have to be able to talk with different API for github, gerrit and jira.

Few notes:
* Email doesn't really work (just ignore it)
* A hosted service would not work because some of these are on intranet
* A browser extension may work

Comment: Why do you ignore your e-mail notifications?

Answer (score 0):

If you are a GitHub organizations user, you can have all the issues and pull request and the projects for organizations tab. See the link: https://github.com/blog/2272-introducing-projects-for-organizations

You must manually add the issues and PRs to the projects. AFAIK there is no tool to do it right now. You can still track all your PR's and issues at your git dashboard.